makeinfo can't locate Texinfo/ModulePath.pm
The makeinfo command under the Texinfo toolchain gives the following error:
Can't locate Texinfo/ModulePath.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Texinfo::ModulePath module) (@INC entries checked: /usr/share/texinfo /usr/lib/perl5/5.38/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.38/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.38/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at /usr/bin/makeinfo line 111.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/makeinfo line 115.

How can I install this module or another way to remove this error message?
Tried installing Texinfo::ModulePath on cpan, it's not a package there. This is on Arch Linux. Thanks.

The Texinfo::ModulePath module should be part of the texinfo installation. On my machine (Ubuntu 23.10): sudo apt-get install texinfo, and then running dpkg -L texinfo | grep ModulePath gives: /usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo/ModulePath.pm. Running makeinfo --version gives: texi2any (GNU texinfo) 7.0.3

Apparently my TexInfo installation is missing more than a hundred modules, and Texinfo::ModulePath is just one of them. I must have seriously corrupted the installation earlier somehow (probably when I was installing LaTeX), and reinstalling the package with pacman -S texinfo fixed the issue.
